# Threading in Android. NO idea what to do. SUPER confused

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, view, methods

I have only been using java for a few weeks, and I have no idea what is going on.

I am making a canvas, and I copy-pasted this code from a tutoral, but it has a bunch of errors, which I'm sure only occur because I don't know how to actually set up the code. The tutorial is for people who already know how to do the threading, and I am lost. I have no idea how to fix the errors.

namely:

postInvalidate() "isnt a method" or something, even though it's a built in android function... same with setWillNotDraw and other ones.

I'm super confused and I don't know how to fix these errors.

```
package com.example.routedrawingtest;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;


class PanelThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
        private DrawingPanel _panel;
        private boolean _run = false;


        public PanelThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, DrawingPanel panel) {
            _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            _panel = panel;
        }


        public void setRunning(boolean run) { //Allow us to stop the thread
            _run = run;


        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas c;
            while (_run) {     //When setRunning(false) occurs, _run is 
                c = null;      //set to false and loop ends, stopping thread


                try {


                    c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {

                        postInvalidate();
                }
} finally {
                  if (c != null) {
                      _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                  }
              }
        }
         }




public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


setWillNotDraw(false); //Allows us to use invalidate() to call onDraw()


_thread = new PanelThread(getHolder(), this); //Start the thread that
    _thread.setRunning(true);                     //will make calls to 
    _thread.start();                              //onDraw()
}



public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
try {
    _thread.setRunning(false);                //Tells thread to stop
_thread.join();                           //Removes thread from mem.
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

Comment: The code above is not good, in particular setting the boolean run variable needs to be done with some sort of memory barrier to ensure visibility. Making the variable volatile would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

postInvalidate() and setWillNotDraw() apply to normal View and ViewGroup-based graphics.  Your code is drawing to a Surface.  These graphics methods cannot be mixed and matched in this way.

If you're new and don't know what you're doing, I recommend you throw out all the Surface stuff.  Learn how to design a layout based on Views and ViewGroups and write code for that.  It also does not require any threading.

Start here : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: thanks! though I literally have no idea what to do. How do I change that?

Comment: Try the "My First App" guide I linked above.

Comment: the only problem is that this is for a project and it's required. 

And I don't have time to go back to square 1 because it's to be done for tomorrow! >.<